# Update record number unexpectedly fails

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get this to update a record and was wondering why I cant get this to work?

I can write a new record no problem but the update doesn't work; is it something simply I am missing?

```
else {
echo "ID NOT EMPTY-";
//---inside else statement shows this echo and the $id number printed on screen WHERE should have varible $ID but I changed it to debug
echo "$id";
$SQLstring3 = "UPDATE $Tablename SET(blank='1') WHERE(id='5')";
$QueryResult = @mysql_query($SQLstring3, $DBConnect);
}
```

Comment: $DBConnect work with INSERT and adds my records no problem

Comment: ID field is generated by SQL database

Comment: I think is has somthing to do with the $QueryResult and should be set up a different way

Comment: Remove the `@` to start with - you may be supressing an error. The first set of brackets (around the `SET`) are also not necessary.

Comment: $SQLstring3 = "UPDATE $Tablename SET blank='1' WHERE id='5'";

Comment: $QueryResult = mysql_query($SQLstring3, $DBConnect);

Comment: Ok did that still no update

Comment: @halfer you were right and I was right. I deleted my comments in regards to all that and now OP says "Yeah that was it". waste of time.

Comment: @Adam: bear in mind that items of feedback you get, either in comments or answers, may not work verbatim, and you may need to play around with them a bit to get them working. It's best to persist as much as you can on your own before replying that it does not work. If you really need to reply that it does not work, it is worth supplying information as to _how_ it does not work, as otherwise we have nothing new to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be the way you are using `SET` and `WHERE`. Putting them the parentheses `()` immediately following them might make them seem like a `MYSQL` function, which it tries to execute. What you have is this:

```
"UPDATE $Tablename SET(blank='1') WHERE(id='5')";
```

Try removing the parentheses:

```
 "UPDATE $Tablename SET blank='1' WHERE id='5'";
```

Comment: Still wont UPDATE I even tried changing to a different field that update wont update any field the id field is lowercase so I checked that. the id field is generated by SQL when a record is added not sure if that has anything to do with it its an auto increment.

Comment: @AdamMajowicz that's what we all said but you ignored us. I deleted my comments, seeing they were of no apparent value.

Comment: sorry, I am new at this but thank you ALL for the help